# laravel : return json data from an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have `foreach` I need return each object in this array in `JSON`

Let me present my controller first

```
$childCategory = ChildCategory::whereProductCategoryId( $catId )->get();
                $data          = array();
                foreach ( $childCategory as $childCat ) {
                    $checkChildes = ChildCategoryTwo::whereChildCategoryId( $childCat->id )->count();
                    $hasChildes   = $checkChildes > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";

                    $data[] = $childCat->id;
                    $data[] = $childCat->image;
                    $data[] = $childCat->bg_color;
                    $data[] = $childCat->product_category_id;
                    $data[] = $childCat->translations[0]->name;
                    $data[] = $childCat->translations[1]->name;
                    $data[] = $hasChildes;
                }

                return response()->json( [$data] );
```

the output of data comes like this

```
    [
        1,
        "1561015312.png",
        "#a9dabf",
        1,
        "Drinks",
        "No",
        2,
        "1562500737.jpg",
        null,
        1,
        "Drinks",
        "Yes"
    ]
```

the output is right but the format is wrong, I need it to output something like this

```
[
      {
            id : 1,
            image : "1561015312.png",
            color : "#a9dabf",
            parent_cat : 1,
            name : "Drinks",
            has_child : "No",
      },
      {
            id : 2,
            image : "1562500737.jpg",
            color : null,
            parent_cat : 1,
            name : "Soda Drinks",
            has_child : "Yes"
      }
]
```

Comment: Did you tried `$data[]['id'] = $childCat->id;...`?

Comment: Have you tried grouping your data in the application properly, before encoding it to JSON? If you just concatenate value after value, there is no way to keep track of identifiers

Comment: @mare96 it gives something like this `{
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "image": "1561015312.png"
        },
        {
            "bg_color": "#a9dabf"
        },` witch is not what I want.

Comment: @NicoHaase can you please show me example `grouping your data in the application properly`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
$childCategory = ChildCategory::whereProductCategoryId( $catId )->get();
$data = array();

foreach ( $childCategory as $childCat ) {
    $checkChildes = ChildCategoryTwo::whereChildCategoryId( $childCat->id )->count();
    $hasChildes   = $checkChildes > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";

    $data[] = [
        'id' => $childCat->id,
        'image' => $childCat->image,
        'color' => $childCat->bg_color,
        'parent_cat' => $childCat->product_category_id,
        'name' => $childCat->translations[0]->name,
        'has_child' => $hasChildes
    ];
}

return response()->json( $data );
```

Comment: Thanks this worked fine with me, and in this case I don't need the empty data array `$data = array();`